# WordPress: Deleted Media Files Don't Go Away

Tags: wordpress, file, replace, media

I'm building a web site with WordPress, and frequently need to replace a media file--specifically, a Java project exported from Eclipse to an archive, but the same happens with images. To retain the original file name, I "delete the file permanently" from the media library, then upload the revision.

Unfortunately, when I download the file via a link, I get the "deleted" version instead of the new one.

I have disabled the "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders" option, so I know the file name is consistent over time.

How is it the "permanently deleted" files don't disappear? And why do they supersede their replacements?

Right now, my choice is to upload the revision without deleting the original; WordPress assigns a sequence number to the revision. I need to change links to match, and the downloaded file will contain the sequence number when used (which isn't very tidy).

This is WordPress 6.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem quite a few times. What I do now is just use the plugin called Enable Media Replace: https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-media-replace/ and I don't really have to think about that issue anymore. Maybe this could be an option for you?

Otherwise I think you will have to go in to the database and manually remove the images unfortunately.